# Bind value for "Maximum' property not working on Slider Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to use a ViewModel property on Slider Maximum value, but when I use Binding the slider always show the current value as 0.

With fixed values, it works:

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="16" Value="{Binding SliderStep, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

[image]

But the Maximum value is variable, so I need to Bind it from ViewModel, when  I try do it something goes wrong:

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding SliderMax}" Value="{Binding SliderStep, Mode=OneWay}"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

[image]

ViewModel Piece Code:

```
double sliderStep;
    public double SliderStep
    {
        get
        {
            return sliderStep;
        }
        set { sliderStep = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SliderStep");
        }
    }

    double sliderMax;
    public double SliderMax
    {
        get
        {
            return sliderMax;
        }
        set {
            sliderMax = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    } 
public SectionGraphicViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            this.Navigation = navigation;
            sectionRep = new SectionRepository();
            this.Sections = sectionRep.GetSections().ToList();
            Items = new List<SectionGraphicModel>();
            foreach (var item in this.Sections)
            {
                var SectionView = new SectionModel(item);
                Items.Add(new SectionGraphicModel(){ Source = SectionView.CachedImageUsed.Source, Desc = SectionView.Desc, Id = SectionView.Id });
            }
            SliderMax = items.Count();
            if (sectionId.HasValue)
            {
                SliderStep = items.FindIndex(x => x.Id == sectionId);
            }
            else
            {
                SliderStep = 0;
            }
        }
```

The Maximum value on this example is 16, I tested with different values and the result is the same.
I tested only on Android simulator. I don't know if it happens on iOS.

PS: Just to avoid misunderstanding, I need to make the Maximum property Bind a value from VM, and OneWay, the control will be disabled from UI, just showing the value from VM.

Comment: I just made a demo its working fine. Maybe you can upload a repo to further enable us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set properties in an order that ensures that Maximum is always greater than Minimum, Maximum should be set before Minimum in xaml:

```
<Slider  BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" Maximum="{Binding SliderMax}" Minimum="0" Value="{Binding SliderStep}" IsEnabled="False"  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" ></Slider>
```

If you want to disable the UI, set:

```
IsEnabled="False"
```

Refer: [slider#precautions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/slider#precautions)

Comment: It worked, the answer is put the Maximum value before Minimum, just changing the position worked. 
TKS a lot!

Comment: I have set this way: <Slider Maximum="{Binding MaxValue}" Minimum="0" Value="{Binding UpperValue}" /> still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I did not read the question correctly. The issue is just binding mode

```
Value="{Binding SliderStep, Mode=TwoWay}
```

This should do it.

**PS**: Whenever you upload a sample repo remove all your bin/obj files from all shared and target projects. Your project is less than 2 MB but the zip I downloaded because of bin/obj was 50+ MB.

Comment: Dont work, when I set TwoWay on Blue Slider, it changes the value to Zero, and yellow one starts with Zero too.

Comment: Just to clarify, I dont want to change the values in the screen, thats why is OneWay. I only want it starts with the correct value from ViewModel, like the yellow does with the fixed value.

Comment: you want the slider to not move from the UI? just via VM

Comment: Yes, the slider will be disabled, just showing the position. This I have already working on other pages. The problem here is set the Max value from VM.

Comment: then just set the `IsEnabled="False"`

Comment: Set to false, but still not working, just disabled.